# How to call an API in visual basic?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call an API service in visual basic, and then the idea is to use the jsonparser to pull specific data from this.

I get "empty" response here. When I use Postman it works.

```
Sub getdata()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Datalastcall")
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
    Url = "https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/jobs?include=user,team-memberships.user,stages&filter%5Bstatus%5D=unlisted"
    http.Open "Get", Url, False
    http.SetRequestHeader "X-Api-Version", "20161108"
    http.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Token Token=xxx"
    http.Send
    httpGET = http.ResponseText
    Cells(1, 1) = http.ResponseText
```

Comment: hey how do you retrieve the token?

Comment: The token i Create in Teamtailor  - its added as a fixed header in every request. So basicall i d not use "XXX" I do you the right token of course

Comment: Try http.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/vnd.api+json"

Comment: Another idea: What is the status code?

Comment: I don't see what the actual issue is? Is your code throwing an error? If so, what is it and which line? (I suspect it's: `http.Send`?). If not, than what is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Zac As he writes in his question: the response is empty but it shouldn't.

Comment: @Nirostar my bad.. completely missed that

Comment: Basically the response is fully empty, in postman it is a significan json output data "file" :

Comment: @VictorLarsson What does http.Status return?

Comment: Tried the "accept" part - did not work. still empty.

Comment: @nirostar it returns "401"So basically it says its not authorized then.. Then I dont get why.. the headers used in postman works "Authorization: Token Token=xxx" and x-api-version:20161108

Comment: @VictorLarsson Ok this means "Unauthorized" https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401. Something with the authorization doesn't work in your code. Maybe you add the Code of your Postman call to your question? You can get it by clicking the small Code button under the send Button in Postman.

Comment: Now I got it to work..... the error was in the Authorization... it should say token instead of Token... apparently case sensative..

Comment: @nirostar THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!! You made my day after several hours on this!!

Comment: @VictorLarsson No Problem :D Would you mind to mark my Answer if it is correct?

Comment: @VictorLarsson Are you already away?

Comment: Hi back now. yes will mark. THank you

Comment: @Nirostar Would you be able to maybe help me with my other question that i posted aswell? Been struggeling for a day now.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969898/vba-json-parser-with-same-name-value-vba-json-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments it should say `token =` instead of `Token =`.