# VBA Json parser with same name value VBA json parser

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following JSON data

```
  "data": [
        {
            "id": "816051",
            "type": "jobs",
            "links": {
                "careersite-job-url": "https://workoab.teamtailor.com/jobs/gdsgds",
                "careersite-job-apply-url": "https://workoab.teamtailor.com/jobs/816051-0220-gdsgds/applications/new?secret=d93b3a3a-c433-4564-a21c-d07096060365",
                "careersite-job-apply-iframe-url": "https://workoab.teamtailor.com/jobs/816051-0220-gdsgds/applications/new?iframe=true&secret=d93b3a3a-c433-4564-a21c-d07096060365",
                "self": "https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/jobs/816051"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "apply-button-text": "",
                "body": "<p>Används ej.</p>",
                "end-date": null,
                "human-status": "unlisted",
                "internal": false,
                "picture": null,
                "pinned": false,
                "start-date": null,
                "status": "unlisted",
                "tags": [],
                "title": "blablablabal",
                "pitch": "Används ej.",
                "external-application-url": "",
                "name-requirement": "optional",
                "resume-requirement": "optional",
                "cover-letter-requirement": "optional",
                "phone-requirement": "optional",
                "created-at": "2020-01-24T09:19:53.940+01:00",
                "sharing-image-layout": "default",
                "mailbox": "job-d93b3a3a-c433-4564-a21c-d07096060365@inbound.teamtailor.com"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "stages": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/jobs/816051/relationships/stages",
                        "related": "https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/jobs/816051/stages"
                    },
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494024"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494023"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494022"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494021"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494020"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494019"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494018"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494017"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494016"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494015"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494014"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494013"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494012"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stages",
                            "id": "4494011"
```

I am trying to get all of the stage ids here with the VBA jsonparser, but I dont manage to get it - i can get all other data...ay.

I have tried to use Select Case item.name and Case "data" - but then i dont know how to call that data - or maybe my idea is just wrong. Ie i tried below "for each item" to add "select case "id" but that just gave me an error..

My code is currently like this - which does not return the different levels of "id"

```
Option Explicit
Sub getdata()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Datalastcall")
Sheets("DataLastCall").Select
Dim i As Long
i = 2
Dim nexturl As String
nexturl = "https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/jobs?include=stages&filter%5Bstatus%5D=unlisted"
Dim http As Object
Dim Url As String
Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/vnd.api+json"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Api-Version", "20161108"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "My Token"
        .Send
    End With
JSONresp = http.ResponseText
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JSONresp)
Dim dataitem1 As Dictionary
Dim dataitem2 As Dictionary
Dim p As Long
p = 3
For Each dataitem1 In jsonObject("data")
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = dataitem1("attributes")("title")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = dataitem1("id")
    last = jsonObject("links")("last")
    nexturl = jsonObject("links")("next")
    For Each dataitem2 In dataitem1("relationships")("stages")("data")
        ws.Cells(i, p) = dataitem2("id")
       p=p+1 
    Next
i = i + 1
p=3
Next

End Sub
```

I get invalid procedure. I have tried several other ways with connecting with (1) as it seems the second data set is another array, and select case etc, but i cant get it to work.. the code works fine getting all other data for me. I also tried to change between "as dictionary" and "as object"

I would really appreciate any help on how to get the different "id"s under stages. I guess the problem is multiple levels of same names of variants. ie both "data" and "id" ?

```
output now looks like this... ie not getting each different stage id - and not matchning to my other "gets"
Jobname      JobID Stageid1 Stageid2 Stageid3
Blablajobb   1234  567      567      567
BLANK?!      Blank 568      568      568
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure which library you use for this so I couldn't test it. But my guess is that you first need a dictionary Item or 2. You have to iterate over the first data array and then over the underlying data array in the `relationships/stages` object.
Something like this should work:

```
Dim dataItem1 As Dictionary, dataItem2 As Dictionary
For Each dataItem1 In jsonObject("data")
    For Each dataItem2 In dataItem1("relationships")("stages")("data")
        ws.Cells(i, p) = dataItem2("id")
        ws.Cells(i, p + 1) = dataItem2("id")
        ws.Cells(i, p + 3) = dataItem2("id")
        i = i + 1
    Next
Next
```

or if you only want the first item from data (or there only is one item per call) you could also do:

```
Dim dataItem1 As Dictionary
For Each dataItem1 In jsonObject("data")(1)
    ws.Cells(i, p) = dataItem1("id")
    ws.Cells(i, p + 1) = dataItem1("id")
    ws.Cells(i, p + 3) = dataItem1("id")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, but some thing is not fully working here. So what i get i like this  as output 
4524917 4524917 4524917 ie it does no seem to take the second "id" item but only the first several times. Also for some reason it does not match with the record of Jobid..

Comment: I think i figured it out myself now with your help more or less! You are my hero man! updated with correct code